# SQLite Insert fails silently on BlackBerry

Tags: sqlite, blackberry

I'm trying to insert some data into an existing SQLite table. The table and the database were created using the same API, but for some reason insertion doesn't work, and never gives me an error message.

I'm testing this on the BlackBerry 9550 simulator.

Here is my query:

```
final String insertQuery
    = "INSERT INTO 'Auth'( "
        + "'" + USER_ID_KEY + "', "
        + "'" + USER_NAME_KEY + "', "
        + "'" + USER_PASSWORD_KEY + "' ) "
        + "VALUES ( "
        + userId + ", "
        + "'" + username + "', "
        + "'" + password + "' ) ";
```

And the code I use to run it:

```
final Statement insertOrUpdateStatement;

insertOrUpdateStatement
    = database.createStatement(insertQuery);

insertOrUpdateStatement.prepare();
insertOrUpdateStatement.execute();
insertOrUpdateStatement.close();
```

It executes just fine, I get no error messages, but the data is never inserted. I've used 3 different SQLite browsers and the BlackBerry API to confirm this.

I've tried using explicit transactions, too, and that doesn't work either. I've searched for similar problems, tried lots of variations on this code, and nothing works. Help?

Comment: Here is the entire class that implements the login function I'm using to test this.

[link](http://www.pastie.org/2174270)

Comment: After over a day of screwing around with no success, it finally started working. I can't tell what, if anything, I did differently this time. This is the flakiest development environment I've ever used, other than an ancient COBOL editor/compiler.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is because you have an excess of single quotes around your table and fields.  Have you tried to remove the quotes from the insert syntax, e.g.

```
final String insertQuery
         = "INSERT INTO Auth(USER_ID_KEY,USER_ID_KEY,USER_PASSWORD_KEY) "
            + "VALUES ("
            + userId + ", "
            + "'" + username + "', "
            + "'" + password + "' ) ";
```

Comment: The reason I assume, is because Sqlite is not one of my areas of expertise, however your query would crap-out in mySQL or SQL Server -- so I assume it would here as well.

Comment: Not my area of expertise either, I just tried to stay as close as possible to the code examples I've seen. I removed the quotes and nothing has changed. Even if it was a syntax error, I should get an exception, not this silent failure.